# How to display data between two dates based on android spinners selected item from sqlite db?

Tags: android, sqlite, spinner

I have spinner from which we can choose an item. And also having two buttons to choose FROM date and TO date. Display data Based on the item chosen from category and between FROM date and TO date. How to achieve this.

Is this following query correct
`SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE category = ? AND FromDate >= ? AND ToDate <= ?` in android sqlite. Can anyone help me pls.

### My Db schema

## id  |  dates   |  currency  | merchant |  payType |  category

## 1 | 2011-9-9  |   dollar |     more    |   debit  |     personal

## 2  | 2011-9-12 |    euro  |     honda   |   cash   |     Business

Comment: Show us your schema; show us some sample data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, your YYYY-MM-DD date format looks good; make sure the TO and FROM dates are formatted as strings the same way. The query:

```
SELECT * FROM TableName where category = ? and dates >= ? and dates <= ?;
```

or as Pratik suggested

```
SELECT * FROM TableName where category = ? and dates between ? and ?;
```

As requested, here's a possible SQLiteDatabase query statement:

```
Cursor cursor = db.query("TableName", null,
                         "category = ? and dates between ? and ?", 
                          new String[] {"personal", "2011-09-07", "2011-09-10"},
                          null, null, null);
```

Where, naturally, you'd replace the `selectionArgs` strings with the values from your spinner and FROM and TO dates.

I just noticed that your dates in the table shown do not have leading zeros in the month and day fields; you need these for the comparison to work correctly since you are actually comparing text strings. Note:  `"2011-09-10" < "2011-9-9"`  but `"2011-09-10" > "2011-09-09"`

Comment: can you please suggest the above query by SQLiteDatabase query methods.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I corrected it. Can you please see my question "ListView not updating after inserting data through an Android DialogBox?" in StackOverFlow and Could you give some suggestions.. waiting for your reply.....

Comment: @Ria, perhaps you could accept this answer. Accepting answers provides some incentive for people to spend time on your questions!

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should read [SQL as Understood by SQLite: Date And Time Functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) so you are aware of how SQLite handles date and time in queries.  Luckily looking at your data suggests you are using the correct time format

So with this in mind your example query would become

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE category = ?
 AND FromDate >= date(?) AND ToDate <= date(?)
```

however looking at your schema and your response to some of the answers you are probably looking to do something like:

```
  myDB.query(myTable,null,"category = ? AND dates BETWEEN date(?) AND date(?)",
       new String[]{selectedCategory, startDate, endDate}, null);
```

DOn't forget to trim startDate and endDate of any spaces.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE category = ? AND datecolum between FromDate AND ToDate
```

Comment: Is this right return sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + MYDATABASE_TABLE + 
     " WHERE Category = ? AND " + DATE + " BETWEEN " 
     + firstDate + " AND " + secondDate, null);